# How to parse a Javascript variable inside HTML <script> by it's name in R?

Tags: r, xpath

I would like to retrieve the content of a Javascript variable inlined in an HTML webpage.

I can retrieve the `<script>` node by it's position but I would like to know if there is a more flexible approach that could look at the variable name itself - the node position may change.

For example the page URL is https://poloniex.com/marginTrading and I'm looking for the content of the variable `markets_currencies` which contains all the currencies that can be lended. This information is not available through the API.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var loggedIn = false;
var dark = false;
var mobile = false;
var mobileDetected = false;
var usid = false;
var markets = {};
var markets_currencies = {"bySymbol":{"1CR":{"id":1,"symbol":"1CR","name":"1CRedit","canLend":0},"ABY":{"id":2,"symbol":"ABY","name":"ArtByte","canLend":0} ... }};
if (window.top !== window.self) window.top.location.replace(window.self.location.href);
</script>
```

Until now I retrieve the webpage like this :

```
  html <- getURL("https://poloniex.com/marginTrading", followlocation = TRUE)
  doc = htmlParse(html, asText=TRUE)
  plaintext <- xpathSApply(doc, "//script", xmlValue)
  cat(paste(plaintext[[5]], collapse = "\n"))
```

But until going further I realize that the `<script>` node position where the variable is stored may change and it's not a flexible solution. What would be the best approach to achieve this ?

Thank you,

Comment: `script` position may change or `markets_currencies` variable position in script may change?

Comment: In the worst case both `script` and `markets_currencies`'s position may change.